# Mixed mode assembly error in .NET 4.5 class library handling SSIS 2012 project

Tags: wcf, ssis

i am trying to create a .NET 4.5 class library to deploy ETLs on server using SSIS 2012 Project deployment model.
The problem is that when attempt to create environments or alter a folder i get this error:

**Operation 'Alter' on object 'CatalogFolder[@Name='FolderName']' failed during execution.**

Foe example when i tey to deploy an ispac like these

```
IntegrationServices integrationServices = new IntegrationServices(new SqlConnection(connection));
Catalog catalog = integrationServices.Catalogs[parameters.Catalog];
CatalogFolder folder = catalog.Folders[parameters.Folder];
using (Project project = Project.OpenProject(parameters.ProjectFileName))
{
      projectName = project.Name;                        
      project.Save();
}
byte[] stream = File.ReadAllBytes(projectFileName);

if (folder.Projects[projectName] != null)
     folder.Projects[projectName].Drop();

Operation operation = folder.DeployProject(projectName, stream);

folder.Alter();
```

folder.Alter(); throws the above exception. The inner exception said that:

"Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information."

so i have tried to add a configuration file to class library with these lines:

```
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
```

but the application still not work.

This class library is call by another one and the parent is use in a wcf service.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think "startup" tag and "useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy" attribute is to put on config file of the application that run your wcf service.

So, because I suppose you use WcfHost to launch your service, try to put:

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true" />
```

on app.config of WcfHost. Usually you can find at:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio XX.0\Common7\IDE\WcfSvcHost.exe.config

(change XX with the version of Visual Studio you use)